# Check Directories in C# using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with the following Linq query?  I'm trying to find the directory with the highest aphanumerical value.

```
        DirectoryInfo[] diList = currentDirectory.GetDirectories();

        var dirs = from eachDir in diList
                   orderby eachDir.FullName descending                    
                   select eachDir;
        MessageBox.Show(dirs[0].FullName);
```

EDIT:

The above code does not compile, the error that the compiler generates is:

```
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.IO.DirectoryInfo>
```

Comment: Isn't the compiler error telling you what the problem is?

Comment: Yes - sorry, I've updated the post accordingly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to access `dirs` as if it were an array or a list. It's just an `IEnumerable<T>`. Try this:

```
var dirs = diList.OrderByDescending(eachDir => eachDir.FullName);
var first = dirs.FirstOrDefault();
// Now first will be null if there are no directories, or the first one otherwise
```

Note that I haven't used a query expression here because it seems pretty pointless for just a single clause. You could put it all into one statement, too:

```
var first = currentDirectory.GetDirectories()
                            .OrderByDescending(eachDir => eachDir.FullName)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't use `var`, the reason for the error would be more clear.

```
    IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> dirs = from eachDir in diList 
               orderby eachDir.FullName descending                     
               select eachDir; 
    MessageBox.Show(dirs[0].FullName);
```

Comment: It's exactly why I hate the 'var' approach, by defining your type it is just soo much more clearer, the var keyword feels like a massive step backwards...

Comment: Wonder if there's some way to get the compiler to warn on use of var when no anonymous types are involved.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply a case of not reading the error message.

The code does not compile, and produces this error message:

> `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.IO.DirectoryInfo>'`

In other words, the `[..]` part does not work with a enumerable, which is the result of using a Linq query.

You have multiple choices, but here are two:

- Convert to an array, and pick the first element
- Use the Linq extension method to grab the first

I think the first method is a poor choice, so here is how the code looks with the second:

```
DirectoryInfo[] diList = currentDirectory.GetDirectories();

var dirs = from eachDir in diList
           orderby eachDir.FullName descending                    
           select eachDir;
var dir = dirs.FirstOrDefault();
if (dir != null)
    MessageBox.Show(dir.FullName);
```

Comment: More a case of not understanding the error message than not reading it

Answer (score 1):

use

```
    DirectoryInfo[] diList = currentDirectory.GetDirectories();

    var dir = (from eachDir in diList
               orderby eachDir.FullName descending                    
               select eachDir).FirstOrDefault();
    if (dir != null)
    MessageBox.Show(dir.FullName);
```